# How do I Alias in Apache properly? Trying to get to another drive in localhost with PHP

Tags: apache, localhost, alias, httpd.conf

I installed Appserv and made a .php:

`D:/Appserv/www/x/y/file.php`

Then I have a folder, like `E:/foldie`.
I want my .php to mess with that folder. I found this online:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
     Alias /foldie/ "E:/foldie"
     <Directory "E:/foldie">
          Options Indexes MultiViews
          AllowOverride None
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
     </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

So I added it to my httpd.config file.Then I added the following to file.php:

```
echo(realpath("../../foldie/"));
```

I was expecting `G:/foldie`, but nothing happened.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't exactly how alias works. Alias means that when Apache receives a request: `domain/<aliased-path>` it will return `path/to/alias`. It works for HTTP requests, but it does not work for working on the local file system -- that does not go through Apache.

Comment: Alright. So how do I get my .php to access the folder in the E: drive?

Comment: Well, the direct route is probably going to be `"file:///e:/foldie"`. In Linux I'd use a symlink to do what you're trying, but PHP does not recognize the Windows links...

Comment: I am using Apache in localhost. How do I use Alias to access the folder?

Comment: PHP does not use Apache's aliasing. You will need to use relative or absolute paths in the file-system to reference it in PHP. If you are simply going to localhost/foldie, that will work though.